# Schur functions on Sage.

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, math-software

Let $p$ be a symmetric polynomial. Then $p = \sum_{\lambda} a_{\lambda} s_{\lambda}$, where $s_{\lambda}$ are Schur functions and $a_{\lambda}$ are coefficients. Are there some function in Sage which computes $a_{\lambda}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=017384562579735769466:s27byrlaffu&q=schur%20functions

Comment: The first couple of code examples here are what you need: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/sf/sfa.html